# Simple slideshow with jQuery (won't go beyond first child)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a simple slideshow, but it only slides to the second image:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/RCQUx/1/

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    $('.img:first').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
    });

});
```

I'm aware I need to use a `$(this)` selector. Is there a way to do so, without traversing from `.next`? There are often cases where `.next` will either be a sibling, or a descendent, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because `.img:first` will always return the same element. Once an element is faded out you can move it to the end of the queue.

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    $('.img:first').stop(true, true).fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).next().fadeIn().end().appendTo(this.parentNode);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Adq5u/)

Comment: Is there a way of creating a slideshow, regardless of whether `.next` is a parent, a sibling, etc?

Comment: @tmyie there are always some way to do things... but everything will depend on the target html....